# How do I print/write data to a new line in a file in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

```
    FileOpen(1, filename1, OpenMode.Output)
    For index = 0 To 0
        PrintLine(1, students_name, correct)
    Next
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

^^This is the code I am using now, but each time it writes to the file, it erases the data that was there before - I need it to write to the next line in the file instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the For loop for this?  The loop is not changing any data.  I could be wrong

Comment: Is this code really VB.NET? If yes why you don't use the appropriate NET Framework methods? Or it is VB6? By the way a loop from ZERO to ZERO is spectacular.

Comment: My guess is there is an OpenMode.Append. That said this is really old Basic code. I suggest you look into .Net support for files. VS has some walk through topics. Or if you "code first" right click and look under the snippets for file support.

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenMode.Append.  OpenMode.Output deletes the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

```
IO.File.AppendAllText(filename1, students_name & vbTab & correct)
```

Notice how this is suddenly much more readable, and in fact every character now makes sense. Generally, as you convert your legacy code, it should look more concise, easy to read and comprehend.

My VB6 knowledge is rusty, so I [had to peek at documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.printline(v=vs.110).aspx) for what `PrintLine` with 3 parameters means:

> PrintLine(1, "Hello", "World")   ' Separate strings with a tab.